# localStorage won't keep values after refresh or navigation from address bar

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, local-storage

I've implemented Private Routes on my React app and it's working *almost* fine: if I try to hit any route by typing directly at the URL address bar and I'm not logged in, I'm redirected to `"/login"`; if I'm successfully authenticated, I'm able to navigate to every route with no problem as long as I do it *inside* the app (by using navbar); however, if I'm logged in and try to navigate to any route from URL bar or refresh the page, I'm being redirected to `"/login"`. I've found out that it was due to not having a persistent state saved at `localStorage`, causing the state being lost on every refresh, so I've created a custom hook:

**usePersistedState.js**

```
function usePersistedState(defaultValue, key) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    const stickyValue = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
    return stickyValue !== null ? JSON.parse(stickyValue) : defaultValue;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
}

export default usePersistedState;
```

The custom hook, however, is also misbehaving. Although it's setting the key-value pairs correctly at `window.localStorage`, which I can confirm right after a successful login, the undesired behavior still happens. Somehow, refreshing the page or navigating to any route directly from URL address bar is setting `localStorage` keys to <strike>their default values</strike> `undefined` instead of keeping the previous ones, except for `"loaded"` (below), which remains as `true`. I *know* there's something wrong with my code, but I just can't see where the mistake is.

**AuthContext.js**

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = usePersistedState(null, "username");
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = usePersistedState(
    false,
    "auth"
  );
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = usePersistedState(false, "loaded");

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("/authenticated")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.statusCode !== 401) {
          return { data: response };
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return { data: { isAuthenticated: false, user: "" } };
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setUser(res.data.user);
        setIsAuthenticated(res.data.isAuthenticated);
        setIsLoaded(true);
      });
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {!isLoaded ? (
        <h3>Loading...</h3>
      ) : (
        <AuthContext.Provider
          value={{ user, setUser, isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated }}
        >
          {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default AuthProvider;
```

**authenticated.js**

```
router
  .route("/")
  .get(passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
      isAuthenticated: true,
      user: req.user.first_name,
    });
  });

module.exports = router;
```

I think these are the relevant parts to the issue I'm facing. If you need to see how I'm handling other things like login, private routes, etc, just ask me and I'll edit the post. This is my very first personal project, I'm putting a lot of effort and love on it, but I'm also too tired and it's been frustrating since this is pretty much the last thing to be done before finally deploying it.

**EDIT:**

**PrivateOutlet.js** (This is where I'm checking the `isAuthenticated` status read from `AuthContext`)

```
function PrivateOutlet() {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const location = useLocation();

  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <Outlet />
  ) : (
    <Navigate to="/login" replace state={{ path: location.pathname }} />
  );
}

export default PrivateOutlet;
```

**Router.jsx**

```
function AppRouter() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" exact element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateOutlet />}>
          <Route element={<Layout />}>
            <Route path="/diary" element={<Diary />} />
            <Route path="/results" element={<Results />} />
            <Route path="/details/:movieId" element={<Details />} />
            <Route path="/settings" element={<Settings />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default AppRouter;
```

Lastly, the `AuthProvider` is wrapping my `App` component at `index.js`.

Comment: Can you share the custom route components that are checking the auth status and redirecting?

Comment: Done! Also, I've taken a closer look and found that the values at `localStorage` aren't actually returning to their default, but are being set as `undefined` instead. It seems that when `useEffect` at `AuthContext.js` is triggered at page refresh, it can't get `res.data.user` and `res.data.isAuthenticated`, thus returning `undefined`

Comment: I see. That's useful information. `return { data: response };` in the `.then` block seems a little odd. What is the value of `response` here? Is there a nested `data` property in there or similar, or maybe the auth values are in a different property?

Comment: I fixed it! Thanks to your last comment, I was able to identify some errors in my previous logic and undid the mess on that `axios` promise, reducing it to a single `.then` and tapping correctly into the response object data to update my custom hooks. In my previous code the promise wasn't even getting the response from `/authenticated`, which caused the `undefined`, so the state was being set by `/login` only, and after that it was never updated again, being lost on page refresh